# plotlyで、グラフを重ねて表示させたい。

Tags: python, plotly-python

plotlyで、グラフを重ねて表示させたいのですが、うまく表示できません。
現在のコード(Python)

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

import plotly.graph_objs as go 
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

n_legends = 12
x = np.arange(0, 1, .01)
y = np.random.rand(n_legends, 100) + \
  np.arange(n_legends).reshape(-1, 1)

def get_colorpalette(colorpalette, n_colors):
    palette = sns.color_palette(
        colorpalette, n_colors)
    rgb = ['rgb({},{},{})'.format(*[x*256 for x in rgb])
           for rgb in palette]
    return rgb

colors = get_colorpalette('hls', n_legends)
data0 = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y[i], name='凡例 {:02d}'.format(i),
        marker={'color':colors[i]}, mode='lines')
    for i in range(n_legends)]

data1 = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y[i], name=' {:02d}'.format(i),
        marker={'color':colors[i]}, mode='lines+markers')
    for i in range(n_legends)]

layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(title=dict(text="x_axis", font=dict(size=16)), tickfont=dict(size=16), autorange=True))

fig = dict(data=[data0, data1], layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig)
```

エラー

```
colors = get_colorpalette('hls', n_legends)
data0 = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y[i], name='凡例 {:02d}'.format(i),
        marker={'color':colors[i]}, mode='lines')
    for i in range(n_legends)]

data1 = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y[i], name=' {:02d}'.format(i),
        marker={'color':colors[i]}, mode='lines+markers')
    for i in range(n_legends)]

layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(title=dict(text="x_axis", font=dict(size=16)), tickfont=dict(size=16), autorange=True))

fig = dict(data=[data0, data1], layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig)
colors = get_colorpalette('hls', n_legends)
data0 = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y[i], name='凡例 {:02d}'.format(i),
        marker={'color':colors[i]}, mode='lines')
    for i in range(n_legends)]
​
data1 = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y[i], name=' {:02d}'.format(i),
        marker={'color':colors[i]}, mode='lines+markers')
    for i in range(n_legends)]
​
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(title=dict(text="x_axis", font=dict(size=16)), tickfont=dict(size=16), autorange=True))
​
fig = dict(data=[data0, data1], layout=layout)
​
py.iplot(fig)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e7ad04250d7b> in <module>
     17 fig = dict(data=[data0, data1], layout=layout)
     18 
---> 19 py.iplot(fig)

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py in iplot(figure_or_data, show_link, link_text, validate, image, filename, image_width, image_height, config, auto_play, animation_opts)
    382 
    383     # Get figure
--> 384     figure = tools.return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate)
    385 
    386     # Handle image request

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py in return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate_figure)
    551 
    552         try:
--> 553             figure = Figure(**figure).to_dict()
    554         except exceptions.PlotlyError as err:
    555             raise exceptions.PlotlyError(

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_figure.py in __init__(self, data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    582             is invalid AND skip_invalid is False
    583         """
--> 584         super(Figure, self).__init__(data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    585 
    586     def add_area(

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __init__(self, data, layout_plotly, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    144 
    145         # ### Import traces ###
--> 146         data = self._data_validator.validate_coerce(
    147             data, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=self._validate
    148         )

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid, _validate)
   2671 
   2672             if invalid_els:
-> 2673                 self.raise_invalid_elements(invalid_els)
   2674 
   2675             v = to_scalar_or_list(res)

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in raise_invalid_elements(self, invalid_els)
    289     def raise_invalid_elements(self, invalid_els):
    290         if invalid_els:
--> 291             raise ValueError(
    292                 """
    293     Invalid element(s) received for the '{name}' property of {pname}

ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property of 
        Invalid elements include: [[Scatter({
    'marker': {'color': 'rgb(220.16,95.0272,87.03999999999999)'},
    'mode': 'lines',
    'name': '凡例 00',
    'x': array([0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 , 0.11,
                0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.22, 0.23,
                0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3 , 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.35,
                0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47
```

どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？
お手数をおかけしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property ...` と表示されているので、おそらく `fig = dict(data=[data0, data1], layout=layout)` の `data=[data0, data1]` の部分を flatten すればよいかと思います。`data=data0+data1`

Comment: ありがとうございます。`data=data0+data1`に変更することで、自分のやりたかったことが出来ました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

`Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property ...` と表示されているので、
おそらく `fig = dict(data=[data0, data1], layout=layout)` の `data=[data0, data1]` の部分を flatten すればよいかと思います。`data=data0+data1`

---

*この投稿は [@user39889 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/76027/plotly%e3%81%a7-%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%95%e3%82%92%e9%87%8d%e3%81%ad%e3%81%a6%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment86111_76027) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*